# AFNetworking not working

Tags: ios, macos, swift, afnetworking-2

I'm new to swift and iOS development and am having some issues with AFNetworking. I am using the following code taken from [here](https://medium.com/@aommiez/afnetwork-integrate-swfit-80514b545b40) :

```
class AFNetCmd {


final func go () {
    let manager: AFHTTPRequestOperationManager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()


    manager.GET( "http://www.google.ca/",
        parameters: nil,
        success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,responseObject: AnyObject!) in
            println("JSON: " + responseObject.description)
        },
        failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,error: NSError!) in
            println("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
    })

    }
}

let test: AFNetCmd = AFNetCmd()
test.go()'
```

No code ever prints and while I understand that the code block will exit before any request returns as AFNetworking is asynchronous, I was wondering how I can get it to execute?

I've also run it using:

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            self.go()
        })
```

and I still get nothing.

EDIT:

As per a comment I tried:

```
class AFNetCmd {

final func go () {
    let manager: AFHTTPRequestOperationManager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()


    manager.GET( "http://www.google.ca/",
        parameters: nil,
        success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,responseObject: AnyObject!) in
            println("JSON: " + responseObject.description)
        },
        failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,error: NSError!) in
            println("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
    }).start()

    }
}

let test: AFNetCmd = AFNetCmd()
test.go()'
```

and the problem still occurs. Ive also tried the `.waitUntilFinished()` method. Further, I tried sending requests using Alamofire and the same issues arise. Mind you I am creating a OSX cmd line app and its being run in xcode. Could there be some settings that are preventing network connections?

Comment: you should call session start. something like this

Comment: at the end of `manager.get(...)` I added `manager.get(...).start()` and using dispatch_sync causes the program to wait. Not using dispatch_sync causes the program to exit with code 0.

Comment: try manager.start() you should run it inside your function

Comment: manager is a AFHTTPRequestOperationManager type and doesn't have the start method. `manager.get()` returns a AFHTTPRequestOperation object which I assign to a request variable and then call `request.start()` from there and I still get nothing. I also tried calling `start()` and `waitUntilFinished()` in various combinations and I still get nothing. Further, I tried to connect to a local server and I checked the log files and its not making the connection, I thought it was dropping the connection after starting it. Finally, rather than calling `dispatch_sync` I called `sleep(120)`, nothing.

Comment: you already have it. just run your function self.go() in viewdidload for example. use breakpoints to see if your code entering this method or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question but for some reason it wouldn't run as a swift command line application. I created an iOS app and ran it in the simulator and it worked fine. Any reasons why it won't run networking code as a command line app?